# Show keymap on button in N-panel

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, shortcut

I want to add an operator label that will show the keymap for the given operator.
How can this be done if operator is in N-panel?
If operator is added to the Object menu, then the keymap will be displayed automatically.
But for N-panel it doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some code for your operators, I don't know if what I suggest will work for you.

From this part of the Blender Python API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop  there is a text="" parameter that you can use in the row.operator that might be what you want.

I tried this in an addon I made that uses a button: `row.operator("kf.movobj", text="Move     G", icon='ARROW_LEFTRIGHT')`

And got this result: [image]

Otherwise one can use the bl_label from the class for the operator to get the same result.

Comment: In my addon you can change shortcuts. Therefore, I have to find out each time which key is assigned to the operator. And the text on the button has the same color as the button name. In the menu shortcuts have a darker color. As far as I understand, there are no built-in tools to draw a shortcut.

Comment: I see. That is a lot more sophisticated than anything I've done. I hope you can find a way to do it.